# On which Windows versions is Cloud Files API supported?

Tags: c++, .net, windows, winapi, filesystems

Microsoft [website says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/cloud-files-api-portal) about Cloud Files API (Cloud Sync Engines):

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1709, Windows provides the cloud files
> API.

However, OneDrive that is built using this API can run on earlier Windows versions, including Windows 8.1. I guess that I just need to install all Windows updates or need to install some windows components on Windows 8.1.

Is Cloud Files API supported on Windows 8.1?

Comment: Are you aware that Windows 8.1 has been EOL for quiet some time?

Comment: The API did not exist prior to Windows 10, version 1709. On earlier versions of Windows, OneDrive runs as a "dumb sync client", simply keeping the contents of its folder in sync with the cloud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have tested
[OneDrive on Win 8.1 x64 Version 6.3 (Build 9600)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEonB.jpg)

And [OneDrive on Win 10 x64 Version 1909 (Build 18363.1082)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kirE3.jpg)

Windows 8.1 does not support offline files in the manner Windows 10 is doing. It just synchronizes all files from the server to the client.

I have also tried calling cloud filter API - it is not supported on Windows 8.1

```
Unhandled exception. System.TypeLoadException: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'Windows.Storage.Provider.StorageProviderSyncRootManager'
```